# How to show text to user with snap install hook?

Tags: snap, packaging

Hello I'm creating a snap package and I need to show something to user after install.
How to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. How about this solution:https://askubuntu.com/a/961547/26246 ?